# Graph with expandable nodes, with D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create an SVG graph of nodes with D3, with "expandable nodes."
That is, when one clicks on a node, its siblings are added to the graph (or more
precisely: its siblings in the graph data are added to the graph visualization.)

The visualization uses a d3 force simulation (using D3 v5).  When a node (an SVG
circle) is clicked, the simulation is stopped (in case it was still running, to
make sure there is no new node with no coordinates added in the middle of a
run,) the corresponding nodes and links are added to the corresponding arrays,
then the graph setup is played again.

But something goes wrong as when a node is clicked, a lot of new nodes are added
to the visualization, and are not correctly linked to each other.  Also, if I
wait long enough for the simulation to stop, the nodes are all added at the same
spot, over the clicked node (they are closer and closer as the simulation goes.)

So I guess there is something wrong in the way I update the visualiaztion, but I
cannot figure it out.  I was not able to find any example doing exactly that.
Any idea?

The initial graph when the page is loaded:

[image: initial graph]

The graph after clicking one of the orange circles (the blue one is the root,
already expanded):

[image: graph after clicking]

- `expandable-graph.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Expandable graph test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="expandable-graph.js"></script>
</html>
```

- `expandable-graph.js`:

```js
const data = {
    name: "top", children: [
        {name: "I", children: [
            {name: "I.a"},  {name: "I.b"}, {name: "I.c"}]},
        {name: "II", children: [
            {name: "II.a"}, {name: "II.b"}]},
        {name: "III", children: [
            {name: "I.a"},  {name: "I.b"}, {name: "I.c"}, {name: "I.d"}]}
    ]
};

const width  = 1000;
const heigth = 800;
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", heigth);

const force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(heigth / 2));

// at first, add the top node, and its children by using expand()
const nodes = [];
const links = [];
nodes.push(data);
expand(data);
setup();

function setup() {
    force.nodes(nodes); 
    force.force("link",  
        d3.forceLink(links).strength(1).distance(100)); 

    const linkElems = svg.selectAll("line")
        .data(links)
        .enter().insert("line")
        .style("stroke", "#999")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    const nodeElems = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
          .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
              return colors(d.parent && d.parent.name);
          })
          .style("stroke", "#000")
          .on("click", function(datum) {
              force.stop();
              expand(datum);
              setup();
              force.restart();
          });

    force.on("tick", function(e) { 
        linkElems.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; }) 
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; }) 
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; }) 
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; }); 
        nodeElems.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; }) 
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; }); 
    });
};

function expand(node) {
    if ( ! node.expanded ) {
        (node.children || []).forEach(function(child) {
            child.parent = node;
            // pop up around the "parent" node
            child.x = node.x;
            child.y = node.y;
            // add the node, and its link to the "parent"
            nodes.push(child);
            links.push({ source: node, target: child });
        });
        node.expanded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to simplify your data structure? So rather than updating the initial set of nodes and links when clicking on an element, you simply append nodes and links from an array that is already loaded (separately from the initial vis).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the example above is a simplification. On a click, the corresponding node's neighbours are going to be retrieved from an HTTP request (instead of from the node's `children` property). The idea is more to "explore" and "discover" a graph dynamically, rather than displaying a graph entirely known in advance.

Comment: OK, so when you click, is the data appended to the const nodes = [];
const links = []; arrays? It might be better to just pull the data in as a new variable, creating an array of links {source: parent, target: child}*n, then create circles and links for the "children" and restart the force. A jsFiddle, gist or bl.ock would really help here as I can't replicate what you're seeing exactly. Have you tried .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10)), this should set the nodes at least 10 pixels apart.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, on a click new nodes are appended to `nodes`, and new objects `{source,target}` are appended to `links`.  This happens in `expand()` at the end.  I've never looked at how to publish on bl.ocks.org and, wow, that's easy! 
 This example is available at: https://bl.ocks.org/fgeorges/755474088065f1aa47583996d971b4fa

Comment: I've had another look, but it's going to take me too long to unpack your data structure, I think you should separate out your expand function and expand-on-click, only adding the new nodes and linking to the existing mid-level node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this, I've just found a solution.  So I post it for the record.  Details can be found at https://gist.github.com/fgeorges/755474088065f1aa47583996d971b4fa.  The solution is in `expandable-graph-solution.js`.  As explained in the above Gist, the problems in the initial code were:

- it did not update the alpha, so the simulation did not run again after it already reached the end once;
- it used variables to cache the sets of links and nodes;
- it referenced circle.node, but the class node was never set on node circles.